# Can a player use Fortune to reduce a dice roll?

Tags: age-system, the-expanse-rpg

In The Expanse RPG a player can spend Fortune Points (FP) to improve a test by changing a dice value equal to the number of FP spent.

Can a player also use this mechanic to decrease a rolled value?

For example, when the player has a target number of 10 and rolls 2, 5, 6 (not considering Ability points), can she spend 2 FPs to change the 5 to 2, thus gaining stunt points (SP) while still succeeding the test?

I'm a bit worried that players could (ab)use this rule too much to achieve stunts with a low FP cost, which could also give "free" FPs by using *Addrenaline Rush*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page 17 of the rulebook it says (my emphasis):

> Fortune is used for a number of things, some described later in this book. For the purpose of tests, Fortune is important because you can spend Fortune points, **decreasing** your current score, in order to improve the results of your tests. You can spend Fortune points to make one die show the value of the number of FP you spend, up to 6.

The examples it then gives are both about **increasing** the value of a die. So if you assume the above quote is not a typo, then you can do both - increase or decrease a die value.

The game balance bit comes from **The Churn tracker**.  The tracker advances 1 step every time a player spends Fortune Points to alter a dice roll. (Some other things also cause it to advance).

So if your players alter their dice a lot, they'll just hit the minor, major and epic Churn setbacks much, much quicker!